# AXIOS - No toma el puerto del BaseUrl definido en la instancia

Tags: axios

Mi problema es el siguiente,

Estoy tratando de hacer una peticion de datos de VueJs a Django a traves de las rest API.

Al parecer al hacer la peticion, Axios no toma el puerto que le defino en la URL Base.

Creacion instancia de axios:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const LogApi = axios.create({
    baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/dv'
})

export default LogApi
```

como pueden ver en la siguiente imagen, la peticion echa con postman funciona [image: Postman - funciona]

de lo contrario cuando pruebo a hacer la peticion desde Vue

```
import LogApi from '@/api/LogApi.js'

LogApi.get('/history')
```

y el resultado es el siguiente

[image: Error_Log]

ya probe a cambiar `127.0.0.1:8000` por `localhost:8000`, a borrar los datos de navegacion pero nada ha cambiado.

alguna idea de lo que podria ser ?